# Moving to Linux

Tags: server, remote-access, remote, mediaserver

The family PC is riding off into the sun.

I want to replace it with a Linux solution. I'm looking at Ubuntu and openSUSE. I want to end up with a solution where anyone in my family can access their files securely from a remote location (laptop, desktop, iOS device, Android device, ....). We also use Google for docs, calendar, sites, drive, basically everything so I need compatibility there also.

I'm willing to invest the time to move from Windows and really learn a new OS so I want to know if ...
 1. Ubuntu will meet my families growing needs?
 2. If so, should the solution I'm looking for be housed in one machine or should I build multiple?

Comment: Please post this on the Ubuntu Forums instead, this site is for more specific technical questions. Check out the forums here: http://ubuntuforums.org

Comment: duly noted. appreciate the answers even though it's out of place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ubuntu will meet my families growing needs?

Yes!

> anyone in my family can access their files securely from a remote location (laptop, desktop, iOS device, Android device, ....).

I recommend [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com) for that. It's a cloud storage service that tightly integrates with Ubuntu and you can access your files from any device running Windows, Mac OS X, Ubuntu, iOS or Android.

> We also use Google for docs, calendar, sites, drive, basically everything so I need compatibility there also.

There is an amazing feature in Ubuntu called Unity Web Apps. It allows supported web applications to act as installed ones. Just open a supported webapp in Firefox (Or Chromium. Other web browsers don't work) and you will be prompted to install it with Unity Web Apps. Google Docs and Google Calender are supported!

Ubuntu's mail client, Evolution, supports GMail. But GMail also supports Unity Web Apps.

You can use Sites in Firefox.

About Drive: Unfortunately, Google is lazy and [haven't released a Linux version of the Google Drive client yet](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive). Google [has said there will be one](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/04/google-drive-is-coming-to-linux), but it hasn't been released yet. You can still use it in Firefox however.

[*There is a petition for Google going on to create a Linux version of the Google Drive client.*](http://www.change.org/en-GB/petitions/google-create-a-native-linux-google-drive-application)

> should the solution I'm looking for be housed in one machine or should I build multiple?

One machine is enough!

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand is correctly, you would like a computer where everything is in the cloud? Well Ubuntu has a service called [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/) that is like Dropbox and is also available for Windows Mac Android IOS. And if you have all you files in the cloud then you don't need multiple machines.

I hope that this helps.